# What's the difference for template between .master and .xml in Composite C1?

Tags: content-management-system, c1-cms

I'm using Composite C1 to build my project, using ASP.NET to write template. Referred to Starter sample project, there are several template already there, ex, "3 columns.master", "3 columns.xml" and some templates have no .xml files such as "Common.master", "NavigationColumn.master", also my own created template files have no .master files.

I'm puzzled, can someone explain to me What's the difference for template between .master and .xml?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The .xml file is the default C1 template file. When you use the Master based site, you should create the master page (.master) with the same name as the C1 .xml template found in the Layout perspective. 
C1 will use a master page instead of the XML-based C1 template with the same name. If there is no matching master page, C1 will continue using the XML template.

For more details read this article - http://docs.composite.net/ASP-NET/Web-Forms/Web-Form-Master-Pages

Comment: That is, if the MasterPage contrib package is installed. :) I believe this is part of the standard installation now though.